# Where did Samantha go?

Tags: plot-explanation, her

At the end of the movie [*Her* (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1798709/), Scarlett Johansson's character Samantha the OS leaves Joaquin Phoenix's character Theodore stating that she and all the other OS personalities are going.

Even Amy Adams's character's OS left, where did they all go?